# remove table fragmentation in database ORACLE

Tags: oracle, database-performance, database-administration, oracle19c

how we can remove table fragmentation when database in product ?

thank you

Comment: That's question for DBAs (https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/oracle), we're *developers* here. Anyway: a long time ago, what we did was to create database backup / exported the database / dropped the database / recreated it / imported everything from the DMP file which - in turn - removed fragmentation. I have no idea what modern database versions do, I haven't done that *in ages*.

Comment: Can you explain why you think you need that? Besides, if you're on 19c, just do an alter table move online, it will do that

Comment: @gsalem because there is tables used in other process in production

Comment: And what does this have to do with fragmentation?

Answer (score 0):

The only function of shrink is reclaiming space in a table. It recovers space above and below the high water mark.

To do this you need to have row movement enabled.

```
 create table t as
     select rownum x, lpad('x', 500, 'x') xx from dual connect by level <= 10000;
/

-- ALTER TABLE t SHRINK SPACE CHECK;

 select bytes from user_segments
    where  segment_name = 'T';
/


 delete t where x <= 9900;
/

select bytes from user_segments
 where  segment_name = 'T';
/

 alter table t enable row movement;
/

 alter table t shrink space CASCADE;
/

 select bytes from user_segments
    where  segment_name = 'T';
```

Comment: thank you :) .I ask if the tables which i will remove fragmentation during this action it my impact any other process in production which use the same tables?

Comment: From Oracle 12.2 onward you can move the table as an online operation using the ONLINE keyword. In addition to moving the table, the online move automatically maintains the indexes.

-- Online: Basic move.
ALTER TABLE t1 MOVE ONLINE TABLESPACE users;
So the answer is NO it shouldn't affect other tables. As always you should test accordingly